# Where f'(x) is defined if $f(x)= \left|x-1\right|$

Tags: derivatives

i solved for  f'(x) and i got $\frac{x-1}{\left|x-1\right|}$. i think that this is defined for 1>x>1.  as $\frac{x-1}{\left|x-1\right|}$ can't be defined for x=1 because the denominator will be 0. I don't know if this is correct

Comment: It is defined for $\color{red}{x\ne1}$. Indeed, it is also known as $\operatorname{sgn}(x-1)$, and the sign of $0$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$f’(x)=\frac{x-1}{|x-1|}.$$ For $x>1$ you have that $|x-1|=x-1$, hence $$f’(x)=\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1.$$ For $x<1$ you have $|x-1|=-(x-1)$ and therefore $$f’(x)=\frac{x-1}{-(x-1)}=-1.$$ Finally, for $x=1$ the function is undefined.